# Protractor Session Creation

Tags: protractor

I am facing the below issue while creating the session for protractor. I need help on resolving this error.
[please click here to view the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjXgN.png)

Comment: It is appreciated to paste the error instead of including a pic

Comment: the error is explicit and indicates that you either need to upgrade your browser of downgrade you chromedriver to make them match

Answer (score 0):

This is a mismatch of ChromeDriver v87 and Chrome v86. These versions need to match to work. The latestest version ChromeDriver that matches your browser is 86.0.4240.22 (see https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_86).

You could download this version with webdriver-manager. `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=86.0.4240.22`. If you need to download this file manually, you could download it from the ChromeDriver website https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads